# Need to return a blank

Tags: excel-formula

I enter a date in A1 and a simple A1+21 in A2 to give me a 3 week ahead date.

It then uses the date in A2 to calculate a number of other values in other cells

However if I havent put a date in A1, I need it to return a blank in A2 rather than 21/01/1900.

I'm quite new to excel and am slowly learning how do do various things with functions, but I have a feeling this one is simple but I just cant see or work out how to do it

Comment: please give use what you have in A1 and A2 and a sample data and the formulas you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",A1+21)`

Comment: It should be pointed out that the cell will not be truly blank; it will contain a zero-length string. The [ISBLANK function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ISBLANK-function-983FC90D-3897-43B5-97CC-DB36DE15FD06) will return *False* but the [COUNTBLANK function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTBLANK-function-C72134A2-695E-43AB-A3F3-714AA770F385) (which accounts for zero-length strings as blank cells) will count it as *1*. Keyboard operations like Ctrl+↓ will skip over it as if it had a value.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I needed, its so obvious when I look at it. Cheers